# Table has no column named

Tags: android, database

I keep getting this "Table has no column named" error, I saw few solutions here, but none of them helped me. I did see that I should go to settings/apps and clear data but I couldnt find it on setting, so I hope I'll find answer here.

```
package com.bengu.bvb;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import static com.bengu.bvb.TableData.*;

public class  DataBaseOperation extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int database_version=1;
public String CREATE_QUERY="CREATE TABLE "+ TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+TableInfo.PLAYER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableInfo.PLAYER_Family+" TEXT);";
public DataBaseOperation(Context context) {
    super(context, TableInfo.DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
    Log.d("Database operations","Database created");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb) {
    sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
    Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

}
public void putInformation(DataBaseOperation dop,String name,String family)
{
    SQLiteDatabase SQ =dop.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

    cv.put(TableInfo.PLAYER_Family, family);
    long k= SQ.insert(TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, null,cv);
    Log.d("Database operations", "One raw inserted");

}


package com.bengu.bvb;

public class TableData {
public TableData()
{

}
public static abstract class TableInfo implements BaseColumns
{
    public static final String  PLAYER_NAME="player_name";
    public static final String  PLAYER_Family="last_name";
    public static final String  DATABASE_NAME="player_info";
    public static final String  TABLE_NAME="reg_info";
}
```

now I dont get this error i get another error.

```
 java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:14673)
        at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2473)
        at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.call(SettingsProvider.java:688)
        at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:325)
        at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:275)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

and that is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Menu"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainApp"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_app" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".AddScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_add_screen" >
    </activity>

</application>
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete error and stack dump? I presume "Table has no column named" is not the full error message. The more details you provide, the better the change you will get meaningful comments or answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `_id` column.
Change

```
 "CREATE TABLE "+ TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"("+TableInfo.PLAYER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableInfo.PLAYER_Family+" TEXT);";
```

to

```
 "CREATE TABLE "+ TableInfo.TABLE_NAME+"(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "+TableInfo.PLAYER_NAME+" TEXT,"+ TableInfo.PLAYER_Family+" TEXT);";
```

Comment: THX, it solved the problem but how can I know if it was realy saved in the database?

Comment: You can probably try to query all the rows from the database