# Table has no column named: SQLite odd behavior on insert

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Table has no column named: SQLite odd behavior on insert

I have searched for and read a number of entries for "Table has no column named" like the following:

[Android SQLite issue - table ... has no column named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441927/android-sqlite-issue-table-has-no-column-named)
[Table has no column named](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661540/table-has-no-column-named?s=2|205.3057)

but they do not seem to apply as my app is exhibiting odd "table ___ has no column named ____ (code 1):" errors that depends on what was entered first. The **pet table** is:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PETS + " (" +
                PET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, " +
                VET_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                PET_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                " FOREIGN KEY(" + VET_ID + ") " +
                " REFERENCES vets(vetId) ON DELETE CASCADE);";
```

The **Vet table** is:

```
public static final String SQL_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VETS + "(" +
                VET_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE, " +
                VET_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                ADDRESS1 + " TEXT, " +
                ADDRESS2 + " TEXT, " +
                CITY + " TEXT, " +
                STATE + " TEXT, " +
                ZIP_CODE + " TEXT, " +
                PHONE_NUMBER + " TEXT, " +
                EMAIL_ADDRESS + " TEXT);";
```

I have checked the emulator's DB and the structure is as shown above. I deleted the app's data and unistalled then installed the app. I enter a pet's name:

```
public void addPetName(String name){
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered addPetName");
    try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        values.put(PET_NAME, name);
        db.insert(TABLE_PETS, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "Should have saved " + name + " to the DB");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This was successful (from **LogCat**):

```
DBHelper: Entered addPetName
DBHelper: Should have saved Tim to the DB
```

I then tried to add a vet name:

```
public void addVetInfo(String name, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String zip, String phone, String email){
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "Entered addVetInfo");

        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Log.d(TAG, "Vet name entered is " + name);
        values.put(VET_NAME, name);
        Log.d(TAG, "Address1 entered is " + address1);
        values.put(ADDRESS1, address1);
        Log.d(TAG, "Address2 entered is " + address2);
        values.put(ADDRESS2, address2);
        Log.d(TAG, "City  entered is " + city);
        values.put(CITY, city);
        Log.d(TAG, "State entered is " + state);
        values.put(STATE, state);
        Log.d(TAG, "Zip entered is " + zip);
        values.put(ZIP_CODE, zip);
        Log.d(TAG, "Phone entered is " + phone);
        values.put(PHONE_NUMBER, phone);
        Log.d(TAG, "Email entered is " + email);
        values.put(EMAIL_ADDRESS, email);
        Log.d(TAG, "Add new vet data to table");
        db.insert(TABLE_VETS, null, values);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is unsuccessful (from **LogCat**):

```
SQLiteLog: (1) table vets has no column named petName
SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting zipCode= address2= city= address1= state=         
petName=Tig phoneNumber=null vetName=Springhill emailAddress=

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table vets has no column named petName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO vets(zipCode,address2,city,address1,state,petName,phoneNumber,vetName,emailAddress) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Something is goin on in SQLite that prevents data input to tables depending on which data was input first:

- For pet name input first, input vet name fails. As seen in the **vet table** there is no *petName* column
- For vet name input first, input pet name fails. As seen in the **pet table**
  there is no *zipCode* column

What could be going on with SQLite? Could it be something due to me not opening/closing the DB connection?

Comment: In `addPetname` and `addVetInfo`, after `db = this.getWritableDatabase();` add `ContentValues values = new Contentvalues();` i.e. issue might be re-using `values`.

Comment: I think you're not refreshing your `ContentValues` try to add this to your every function `values = new ContentValues()`.

Comment: Mike T and Jerrol, you're geniuses! I had declared values such that all methods could use it and that was indeed my problem. You suggestion to declare it internal to each method resolves the problem. I didn't think that values would be re-used. I added LogCat output and see that the new inputs are being appended to all inputs added before. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is likely that you are re-using the same instance of ContentValues `values` and thus adding to it. So basically the first use will work but subsequent uses could be problematic.

The solution would be to either use `values.clear()` before adding (putting) values for each method. Or to use a new ContentValues instance for each e.g. use `ContentValues values = new ContentValues();`

The latter being the more common approach.

So for example the **`addPetname`** method could be :-

```
public void addPetName(String name){
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered addPetName");
    try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //<<<<<<<<
        values.put(PET_NAME, name);
        db.insert(TABLE_PETS, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "Should have saved " + name + " to the DB");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

or

```
public void addPetName(String name){
    Log.d(TAG, "Entered addPetName");
    try {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        values.clear(); //<<<<<<<<
        values.put(PET_NAME, name);
        db.insert(TABLE_PETS, null, values);
        Log.d(TAG, "Should have saved " + name + " to the DB");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. As I noted in my comment to yours above, I just didn't think of the fact that 'values' would continue to append values, adding LogCat outputs show this value growth. What you show is a great lesson! Thanks you for your help.

Comment: Two more things: 1) for some reason, and I don't know why, I should have verified what was in `values` as a result of `values.put()` via LogCat but didn't and (b) didn't really understand the ramifications of "Adds a value to the set" in regards to the description of ContantValues' put() method.